# Extended JLabel class not showing in layered pane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, jlayeredpane

In my function called `create()` i am trying to instanciate an object of class `note`, which is an extention of `JLabel`. I then want to add this object to a `JLayeredPane` (known as `lp`) at depth 1, in order to show it above my background image. Instanciation goes fine but the `newNote` object is not displayed.

Here is the code for the note class:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

//This class will be used to instanciate new notes for the user
public class note extends JLabel{
    final static ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(note.class.getResource("semibreve1-removebg-preview.png"));
    //attributes
    private String length;
    private String note1;
    private String code;
    private String val;
    
    //Constructor
    note(String myLength, String myNote){
        super("",image,LEADING);
        this.length = myLength;
        this.note1 = myNote;
        generateCode();
        //System.out.println("note creation confirmed: "+code);
    }
    
    //Getters and setters below
```

And here is the code for my create function.

```
public void create(l,n){
    note newNote = new note(l,n);
    noteObjects.add(newNote);
    newNote.setBounds(0,0,newNote.image.getIconWidth(),newNote.image.getIconHeight());
    newNote.setSize(newNote.getPreferredSize());
    lp.add(newNote,1);
    }
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a valid [mre] with your question. This is not your entire program but a smaller new program that compiles and runs for us, that demonstrates your problem directly for us, and yet is small enough to post in its entirety with your question.

Comment: Did you verify that `image` is not null?

Comment: Does it display on a regular JPanel? Get basic logic working first when using layout manager. Then get it working of a JLayeredPane which is more involved since you need to manually manage the size/location.

Comment: everything is fine, jyust needed to set the opacity to true using `this.setOpaque(true);`

Answer (score 2):

As @Hovercraft [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655156/extended-jlabel-class-not-showing-in-layered-pane#comment121332761_68655156), the problem is likely somewhere else—an image that silently fails to load or an errant component boundary. A [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will allow you to study the problem is isolation and use the result to refine your full program.

Starting from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9629892/230513), I added these lines to the `LayerPanel` constructor to get the image below

```
this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
this.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(n)), JLabel.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
```

This leverages the panel's [layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to position the label in the top right; in contrast, the implementation of `paintComponent()` draws in a fixed position at the bottom left.

[image]

Going forward, critically examine the need to extend [`JLabel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html). As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49469822/230513) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), the `JLabel` itself can control the relative position of text and icon; and the parent [`JComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) can store arbitrary, component-specific properties.